# Allow typing only Arabic characters in Buefy input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

Hello I have working version of html input, where user can only write Arabic letters, however I can't get same functionality using Buefy input.

Here is what I've tried so far.

https://codesandbox.io/s/allow-only-arabic-in-input-gxgzx?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: why didn't you apply a watcher for the  buefy input?

Comment: You can check if the input hexadecimal code is in the range of Arabic alphabet hexadecimal code (https://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536&number=128&utf8=0x&unicodeinhtml=hex)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thanks, I've updated the sandbox with watcher usage for the buefy input, however it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

One day if you migrate to Vuejs3, you may create custom modifiers.